# Eclipse export as runnable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I know SO dislikes this type of questions but after googling and checking SO for close to an hour I am no closer to a solution. I have a package with some classes which together form a GUI based game which runs fine when I do `CTRL-F11` but when I right-click the package->Export->Runnable JAR it is nowhere to be found in the Launch Configuration dropdown, while other packages/projects are.

I would like to be able to run this game outside of Eclipse even if I don't need to now. I have no main methods, my runnable uses acm. `public class SokobanGFX extends GraphicsProgram`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in Javadoc:

http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/program/Program.html

"In many programming environments, objects that are specific instances of a Program
    subclass will run automatically without any special action on your part. For maximum
    portability, you might want to define a static main method as described in the comment
    for the standard implementation of main."

Should be easy to make an executable jar after that.

I'm not familiar with ACM, but based on my observations with the Javadoc, I believe:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new SokobanGFX().start()
}
//http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/program/Program.html#main(String[])
```

Should launch the program.

Comment: Now I managed to export it. Nothing happens when I click the .jar though.

Comment: @user948652 Edited my answer, hope it helps